# Using multiple hicharts on ASP.NET web form but only one shows on the upper section of the page pushing the page header down

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, webforms

I am trying to use the HiChart on my ASP.NET web form using the samplecode given on 
http://dotnet.highcharts.com/dev/Highcharts/Demo/Docs?section=WFFirstChart3

The problem I am facing is that the chart shows up but it shows up on the upper section of the page and does not get confined within the section I am trying to put it in. The header of my page generated in master file gets moved down.

My aspx page looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlCharts" runat="server"> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="rows"> 
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
            <div class=col-sm-5> 
                <hichart:HighChartIncidents ID="hichartIncidents" runat="server"/> </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <hichart:HighChartIncidents ID="HighChartIncidents1" runat="server"/>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Tried putting the toHtmlString() output to asp literal's Text property. The highchart shows in chrome once instead of twice. In IE javascript error 27 shows up and no chart is shown.

Comment: I have resolved the issue of not having the multiple charts display by setting a different chart name for each instance. Now i can see 2 similar charts side by side. The problem is that its working on Chrome but not on IE version 11. No chart is displaying on IE version 11.

Comment: The subject continues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586455/highcharts-programmed-in-for-asp-net-webform-server-control-are-not-displaying

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem was that I was using Response.Write to write the chart html and it was getting written above the page header moving it down.

Secondly, I was using hard coded chart name and this was causing issue with displaying the multiple charts side by side against the same hichart control. To resolve I added a property ChartName and used it to avoid the same chart name for multiple instances of same control.

The issue of IE explorer not showing the chart is still under investigation.

Answer (score 0):

The Highcharts.net API isn't great for web forms because it only uses Response.Write in its example. Using a literal server control does the trick.
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnethighcharts

```
//using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts; //v7.0.1
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts
{
    ID = "chartid",
    Chart = new Chart
    {
        Type = ChartType.Scatter,
        ZoomType = ChartZoomType.Xy
    },
    Title = new Title
    {
        Text = "example"
    },
    Subtitle = new Subtitle
    {
        Text = "example"
    },
    XAxis = new List<XAxis>
    {
        new XAxis
        {
            Type = XAxisType.Datetime,
            Title = new XAxisTitle
            {
                Text = "Date"
            }
        }
    },
    YAxis = new List<YAxis>
    {
        new YAxis
        {
            Type = YAxisType.Linear,
            Title = new YAxisTitle
            {
                Text = "Value"
            }
        }
    },
    Legend = new Legend
    {
        Align = LegendAlign.Right,
        Enabled = true,
        Layout = LegendLayout.Vertical,
        VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Top
    },
    Series = series, //List<Series> adding a SplineSeries for each legend item
};

HighsoftNamespace Highsoft_chart = new HighsoftNamespace();
literal.Text = Highsoft_chart.GetHighcharts(chart, "chartid").ToHtmlString();
```